# Can you give me comments on elegance?

Tags: c, cs50

I have just started to learn how to code and am interested in receiving some feedback on my code (apart from whether it executes a task correctly). I am taking the CS50 online course. The task at hand is to make a greedy algorithm to return change.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   //Prompt user for money value they want in change
   float dollars;
   do 
   {
      dollars = get_float("Change owed: ");
   }
   while (dollars < 0.0099);  //Has to be more than 1 cent

   // Convert total change value to cents, to avoid float/float division
   int cents = round(dollars * 100);

   // Use floor function to round down to closest integer
   int x = floor(cents / 25);

   // Introduce modulus, so that the remainder of previous step division 
   // can be used to determine the next step for number of coins
   int y = floor((cents % 25) / 10);
   int z = floor(((cents - (x * 25) - (y * 10)) % 10) / 5);
   int w = floor(((cents - (x * 25) - (y * 10) - (z * 5)) % 5) / 1);

   //Output is an integer, which is an addition of previous steps
   int a = x + y + z + w;
   printf ("%d\n", a);
}
```

The code above does the work, but I am wondering whether a loop would be quicker at coming up with the output?

Comment: You don't need `floor` when working with `int.` Also, I think you should convert to `cents` inside the loop, and check that as the loop ending condition.

Comment: There's a specific sister site to be used for code reviews: see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @paxdiablo, thanks! I will post it there instead

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, thanks! The infinite loop is a necessity, in case someone is a joker and inputs non-numerical, negative or less than 0.01 values (the code test actually tries a few of those options).

Comment: @WeatherVane, thanks for the floor tip! I put it in as I was worried integer might be rounded up.

Comment: I edited the code so that I could read it; the comparison of the two versions is my review comment ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elegance is a big but quite generic word. I try to address multiple aims concerning programming elegance at once:

#### 1. Algorithmic elegance

> The code above does the work, but I am wondering whether a loop would
>   be quicker at coming up with the output?

As you clarified in your comment, you are not asking about the infinite loop at the beginning where you retry until input data are valid. Hence, I understand that the question is whether a loop should be preferred to the closed computations giving the number of quarters/dimes/nickels/cents.

- The direct computation (using division/modulus) is definitely more elegant than subtracting the amount of another, comparing whether the remainder is sufficient for another coin of that amount. Such a loop would neither improve efficiency nor readability. If a large amount of money is used (compared to the numeric precision of type `float`, such a loop can even deteriorate numeric stability (because floating point operations are not associative) - see also "Variable Type" below.
- If you use an array for the numbers of coins per type and a (sorted) const array for the cent amounts per coin type, a loop can be used to partition the current amount into a set of coints of current type plus a remainder, iterating from larger coins to smaller ones.

  For only four types of coins (= loop iterations), I find this overshoot.
  CPU efficiency will be sligthly lower (loop management, array indexing),
  and flash memory consumption might be a little (ignorable) bit smaller.

  There is one case when this coding style is really more elegant:
  If the United States decide to provide another coin at a new value, you only have to add a single line to your arrays, but not to add another variable and line of program code, so your code is perfectly scalable w. r. t. the next currency reform.
  You have to estimate the probability yourself whether this is going to happen while your program is in use. :-)
- You can save some complexity if you don't have to re-subtract the balance paid in larger coins multiple times but update the remaining amount of money.
- If you are only interested in the total number of coins but not in their types, you only have to count coins and keep in memory the remaining money.
- If you want to optimise for performance beyond the portability of ANSI C, you can look out for CPU instructions that compute the integer quotient and modulus at the same time. Check your CPU instruction set and the corresponding C intrinsic functions (or assembler statements, resp.). But then, you are sacrificing elegance regarding portability and readability!

#### Variable Type

- For the money balance in dollars, the `float` variable type has been chosen - probably in order to divide the dollar number into the cents number.
  In general, integer arithmetics are more stable than floating point arithmetics because floating point arithmetics include rounding even during addition/subtraction, multiplication and type conversion from integers.
  Some very few exceptions to this rule apply when you are handling really big numbers and you can sacrifice some precision, but your coin selection example will not reach this area.

  Instead, you should convert the initial dollar amount to cents (multiply by 100)
  and proceed with cent amounts. 
  Then, no rounding is necessary.
  As pointed out by a comment from @WeatherVane, the `floor()` calls in the code haven't been necessary in the first version of the code because this is the behaviour for float-to-integer conversions required by the standard.
  When starting from integer, the question "`floor` or not?" doesn't even come up.
- Caution, both integers and floats have an upper limit that is determined by the actual type you select (`int`, `short`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned`/`signed`, `uint64_t` etc. - there's a lot to explore if you don't know this yet...).
  Please check the header `<limits.h>` for details.
  As you (more or less) checked the input value against zero, you should also check it against the maximum number you can handle.
- By the way, `float/float` division is not a big issue.
  Floating point numbers are made for division, while integer division is notably expensive on many architectures.

#### Coding style elegance

For all those pieces of software that are not critical to CPU performance or memory size (RAM/ROM), the most important aspect of elegance is maintainability - as a well-known saying goes,

> Code is written only once, but it is read many times.

This aspect partly touches matters of taste, but opinions are deprecated on SO. Hence, we have to limit this to some objective criteria:

- Authors of coding style guides strongly disagree when to open a new line, especially around loops and other `{ }`blocks.
  Still, a great majority of them agrees that you should give each loop body at least one dedicated line.
- Literals such as the number constants in the code are often required to be assigned to macros. 
  This is for good reason, as it lowers the probability to make a mistake at one place and use a correct value in other instances.
  Additionally, it helps when the software requirements change:
  If the United States decided to pay 26 cents per quarter coin, a single line would have to be changed, and we wouldn't have to worry about consistency.
- Variables shall have speaking names. 
  It's a matter of taste how far this goes.
  One rule of thumb I found on this question says

> the name of a variable should have about a tenth as many chars as the variable has lines in the the scope.

#### Conclusion

This code is what we get when we apply all the rules above.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define CENTS_PER_DOLLAR  100uL
#define CENTS_PER_QUARTER  25uL
#define CENTS_PER_DIME     10uL
#define CENTS_PER_NICKEL    5uL

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt user for money value they want in change
   unsigned dollars;
   float    flt_dollars;
   do {
       // I don't know your <cs50.h> library - if there is sth like get_int(), please use it!
       flt_dollars = get_float("Change owed: ");
       dollars     = (unsigned) flt_dollars;
   } while ((flt_dollars >= 0.0) && (flt_dollars < (float)UINT_MAX) && (dollars < UINT_MAX / CENTS_PER_DOLLAR);

   // Convert total change value to cents
   unsigned cents = dollars * CENTS_PER_DOLLAR;

#ifdef COIN_TYPES
   unsigned num_quarters = cents / CENTS_PER_QUARTER;
   // Introduce modulus, so that the remainder of previous step division can be used to determine the next step for number of coins
   unsigned num_dimes    = (cents % CENTS_PER_QUARTER) / CENTS_PER_DIME;
   unsigned num_nickels  = ((cents - (x * CENTS_PER_QUARTER) - (y * CENTS_PER_DIME)) % CENTS_PER_DIME) / CENTS_PER_NICKEL;
   unsigned num_cents    = ((cents - (x * CENTS_PER_QUARTER) - (y * CENTS_PER_DIME) - (z * CENTS_PER_NICKEL)) % CENTS_PER_NICKEL);

   // Total number of coins is sum of previous steps
   unsigned num_coins    = num_quarters + num_dimes + num_nickels + num_cents;

   printf ("%d\n", num_coins);
   printf ("%d\n", num_quarters);
   printf ("%d\n", num_dimes);
   printf ("%d\n", num_nickels);
   printf ("%d\n", num_cents);
#else
   // Quarters
   unsigned num_coins_tmp =  cents / CENTS_PER_QUARTER;
   unsigned num_coins     =  num_coins_tmp;
   cents                  -= num_coins_tmp * CENTS_PER_QUARTER;
   // Dimes
   num_coins_tmp =  cents / CENTS_PER_DIME;
   num_coins     += num_coins_tmp;
   cents                  -= num_coins_tmp * CENTS_PER_DIME;
   // Nickels
   num_coins_tmp =  cents / CENTS_PER_NICKEL;
   num_coins     += num_coins_tmp;
   cents                  -= num_coins_tmp * CENTS_PER_NICKEL;
   // Cent pieces
   num_coins     += cents;

   printf ("%d\n", num_coins);
#endif /* COIN_TYPES */
}
```